# SSRS Textbox BackgroundColor

Tags: reporting-services, background-color

How would I set one BackgroundColor = to another Textboxes BackgroundColor property.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio/Business Intelligence Management Studio:

1. Select textbox (or table cell)
2. In the **Properties** window, you'll see the **BackgroundColor** attribute
3. Click the dropdown arrow to get a list of colour options, or you can type in the color code if you know it

Comment: if textbox1 is "Orange" I am trying to find a way in textbox2 to pull the background color value of textbox1 and use it.

Comment: I'm using SSRS 2005 - I don't see the ability to relate based on another textbox.  Apparently SSRS doesn't have CSS/similar support: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=317635